# ExtJS: make the menu for a button always appear above the button itself

Tags: extjs

The title is pretty self explanatory, I want the menu of a button to be always placed above the button itself

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying the menu's positioning by adjusting its `defaultAlign` and `defaultOffsets` config options.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but if someone is looking for exact then `listAlign :  'bl-tl?',`
Just in case if somebody is looking for example,

```
var cbxSelDomini = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    listAlign :  'bl-tl?',
    hiddenName: 'Domini',
    name: 'nom_domini',
    displayField: 'nom_domini',
    valueField: 'cod_domini',
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    //listClass: 'comboalign',
    typeAhead: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    store: mystore
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nE2sc/1/